# How to pass arguments to 'onclick' attribute function in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am trying to add an 'onclick' event to a checkbox like so

`<input type='checkbox' name="doneTask" value='done' onClick={removeTask(this)}/>`

'removeTask' is defined in the same file

```
 function removeTask(elem){
    
     //use elem

 }
```

I want to pass 'this' as argument but the problem is the event gets fired before the click (probably ) because 'removeTask(this)' is seen as a function call. It works fine when I use

`onclick = {removeTask}`

But I cannot pass 'this' using this method, is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: Isn't the callback supposed to provide you with the "event" object that contains the event target?

Comment: Your code is **calling** `removeTask` and then setting `onClick` to its return value, see the linked question for details. Separately, `this` is not set by React when calling event handlers. If you want to access the element that the handler is attached to, use the `currentTarget` property of the event object the function receives.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, try passing in a callback function if you wanna pass props:
Currently you are only passing the event of the property.

```
onclick = {() => removeTask(prop1, prop2)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass it in a call-back function

```
   onClick={()=>function(this)}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call the function on the click event, you just need to call the function with arguments inside another function like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name="doneTask" value='done' onClick={()=>removeTask(this)}/>
```